# Tiling exterior an exterior corner -are there any other options other than mitering the tiles or using bullnose tiles?

Tags: tile, corner-bead

In the figure below I marked with red the outside corner I am talking about
As far as I can see I could use bull nose tiles ore try to miter the tiles (which seems to be difficult as you need special tools or jigs or to be well trained -to have done this before)

[image]

Update: I guess this is the solution suggested by @kris in the comments
[image]

Comment: Jolly pencil trim and various metal tile trim options   [Schlutter](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Schluter-Systems-Rondec-White-Color-Coated-Aluminum-3-8-in-x-8-ft-2-1-2-in-Metal-Bullnose-Tile-Edging-Trim-RO100W/202608917) has best selection

Comment: Like this one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPksFLWWprk&ab_channel=LandbergTileTV

Comment: Yes but that is not best method of installation. Trim should be embedded in thinset and tiled over  not slipped in under like that